# Make available a variable of a for loop on the outside.. How it is possible?

Tags: java, eclipse, variables, for-loop

Sorry for the bad english but i'm, italian.
Here is the code:

```
String newNameToAdd = "";
    String newBuyedToAdd = "";
    String newFinishedToAdd = "";
    //lista delle persone che la listview visualizzerà
    ArrayList <Game> gamelist = new ArrayList<Game>(); 

    Intent save = getIntent();
    newNameToAdd = save.getStringExtra("newName");
    newBuyedToAdd = save.getStringExtra("newBuyed");
    newFinishedToAdd = save.getStringExtra("newFinished");

    int qw = 10;
    int as = 3;

    String[][] newGame = new String[qw][as];

    for(int i = 0; i <= qw; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j <= as;) {
            newGame[i][j] = newNameToAdd;
            j++;
            newGame[i][j] = newBuyedToAdd;
            j++;
            newGame[i][j] = newFinishedToAdd;
            j++;
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i <= qw; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j <= as; j++) {
             Game[] game={
                            new Game(newNameToAdd, newBuyedToAdd, newFinishedToAdd)};

                }
        }

    for(int i=0;i<game.length ;i++){
            gamelist.add(game[i]);
    }
```

So the error is that the variable game isn't usable on the outside of the for loop. i would use it on the last for loop. I reposte the code

```
for(int i=0;i<game.length ;i++){
            gamelist.add(game[i]);
    }
```

How can i do?

Answer (score 3):

The `game` array doesn't make sense, since you only put one `Game` instance in it, and you create a new `game` array in each iteration of your loop.

I'd replace your bottom two loops with :

```
for(int i = 0; i <= qw; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j <= as; j++) {
         gamelist.add (new Game(newNameToAdd, newBuyedToAdd, newFinishedToAdd));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thats what I was thinking about

Comment: couldn´t you simplify it to `i <= qw * as` in a single loop, since he doesn´t use either `i` nor `j` ?

Comment: @KevinEsche That's a good point (assuming the code posted in the question is not a simplification of the actual code).